# Is it possible to show svg images using Glide on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-glide

Is it possible to show svg image from Firebase Storage using Landscapist Glide on Jetpack Compose?

I tried using 'com.github.qoqa:glide-svg:4.0.2' but it logs error: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Comment: I am not sure about glide, but you can try Coil if you don't mind. Coil supports SVG

Comment: Did you get an answer somewhere else? Currently using Glide already on Jetpack compose and would prefer to use a single Image lib.

Comment: Did any of you succeed w/ SVGs and Glide?

Comment: still haven't found how to do it, meanwhile I switched to png for now